# Are the Gufw default profiles empty?

Tags: 13.10, ufw, gufw

I've just installed gufw on my notebook. I'm trying to setup my laptop with a very secure - roadwarrior - type of configuration. So the choices available in GUFW with a public, home and office profile look very promising.

But then I got worried. Because enabling these profiles didn't do very much, rather nothing at all. I've looked in the documentation, but it seems to me that it isn't very well documented. Any suggestions what would be a good setup for the public/home/office profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Each user need really different rules from another user (P2P, games, servers...). That is the reason for no rules in the preconfigured profiles.
In your home, you'll safe by your router then, the preconfigured policies will be allow.
In a public profile the default policies will be more restricted because you'll into the wild ;)
Best regards :)